# Is there a way to store whatever i append to DOM with js,in local storage in order to retrieve it after page reloads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok,for testing purposes lets say i have a function where it appends `<li>` elements inside an `<ol>`
container,and i want to keep all list items i've added,is there a way to store them in Local Storage (or any other way,locally) so i can retrieve them every time i reload the page ?

I've studied a little bit in [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) api,i did'nt find a method to store a dynamic element like that,but again if there is something i would'nt know to recognize the right practice to do it,since i'm still a student.Any ideas?

```js
var textcounter = 1;
var inputcounter = 1;

function addText() {
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var texttobestored =document.createElement("li");
texttobestored.id = "text" + textcounter;
texttobestored.style.color="red";
texttobestored.innerHTML = "<p>I WANT TO KEEP THIS TEXT</p>";
div.appendChild(texttobestored);
textcounter++;
}
function addInputs() {
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var inputstobestored =document.createElement("li");
inputstobestored.id = "input" + inputcounter;
inputstobestored.innerHTML = "<input placeholder = ContentsToBeSaved>";
inputstobestored.style.color = "blue";
inputstobestored.style.width = "600px";
div.appendChild(inputstobestored);
inputcounter++;
}
```

```css
#div{
width:600px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<ol id="div">
<button onclick="addText()" style="height:100px;width:100px">ADD TEXT</button>
<button onclick="addInputs()" style="height:100px;width:100px">ADD INPUTS</button>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, HTML is just a string that you can retrieve with `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` - you can save that string in localStorage. You need to realize that you'll lose any event handlers that are programmatically assigned when reusing that string.

Comment: In that case, its better to store the information used to construct the elements in localStorage as JSON and just rebuild it every time, and not focus on actually storing domElements. Mostly because users can edit their own localStorage, which would allow them to insert script into your page with full permissions.

Comment: @somethinghere - this "_which would allow them to insert script into your page with full permissions_" is misleading. If done safely, there is no hope of user injected JS being executed when the HTML is placed back into the DOM. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: `localStorage.someProperty = JSON.stringify({listProp1:'listValue1Here', listProp2:'listProp2Here'});` is the easy way to assign. Remove like `localStorage.removeItem(someProperty);`. So yeah, it's best to store the properties in an Object that is converted to a String since Storage only accepts Strings. By the way, I advise against doing most, if not all, of your style with CSS. Just `Element.classList.add('classNameHere')` while having the CSS already set to do what you like. Also, I advise against using `.innerHTML` except to remove multiple Elements with  `= ''`. Reduce your DOM parsing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn True, but if this user is storing `outerHTML` of elements to load in later, there is no really safe way to prevent this dangerous thing, which is why I suggested storing the data and not the html itself. Still important that they consider these caveats and dangers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ez4pq2d/

This function calls saveInput to save the data to localstorage. Then it also generates the
inputs that are saved via `loadInput`.

This just stores the ID, COLOR and WIDTH. But using this as a base you can save additional fields also.

```
function saveinput(obj) {
  saved = localStorage.getItem("items") || "[]"
  saved = JSON.parse(saved)
  saved.push(obj)
  localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(saved))
}

var textcounter = 1;
var inputcounter = 1;

function addText() {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var texttobestored = document.createElement("li");
  texttobestored.id = "text" + textcounter;
  texttobestored.style.color = "red";
  texttobestored.innerHTML = "<p>I WANT TO KEEP THIS TEXT</p>";
  div.appendChild(texttobestored);
  textcounter++;
}

function addInputs() {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var inputstobestored = document.createElement("li");
  inputstobestored.id = "input" + inputcounter;
  inputstobestored.innerHTML = "<input placeholder = ContentsToBeSaved>";
  inputstobestored.style.color = "blue";
  inputstobestored.style.width = "600px";

  saveinput({
    id: "input" + inputcounter,
    color: "blue",
    width: "600px"
  })

  div.appendChild(inputstobestored);
  inputcounter++;
}

function loadInput() {
  inputs = localStorage.getItem("items") || "[]"
  inputs = JSON.parse(inputs)

  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var inputstobestored = document.createElement("li");
    inputstobestored.id = input.id;
    inputstobestored.innerHTML = "<input placeholder = ContentsToBeSaved>";
    inputstobestored.style.color = input.color;
    inputstobestored.style.width = input.width;
    div.appendChild(inputstobestored);
    inputcounter++;
  })
}

loadInput();
```